# How to configure FTP endpoint with @ in the username

Tags: ftp, wso2, vfs, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 to access different FTP and the username for a specific FTP does contain the '@' which is predefined character for the server config.

Here an example of an Endpoint accessing such a FTP with the username 'MY@USERNAME':

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FTPEndpoint">
   <address uri="vfs:ftp://MY@USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/Path?vfs.passive=true"/>
</endpoint>
```

Is there a way to escape the @ for the username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was finally simple by replacing the @ by %40 and it works:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FTPEndpoint">
  <address uri="vfs:ftp://MY%40USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/Path?vfs.passive=true"/>
</endpoint>
```